# Visual studio on windows xp

Tags: visual-studio, memory, windows-xp

i need to run a few visual studios on windows XP and it seems to take up a lot of memory.  i am also running resharper which is a memory hog.

i am running 32 bit XP. How much memory can i put into my machine until i get to the point where the OS hits its limit.

Also, any other ways of running multiple visual studio without such slow performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

32-bit Operating Systems are limited to 4 GB of RAM, which may or may not be enough for you. Also, I think Windows shows 3 GB of RAM if you install 4 GB.

I suggest you switch to 64-bit and upgrade to 8 GB if you can.

**UPDATE:** See Jeff's blog post on the subject: [Dude, Where's My 4 Gigabytes of RAM?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000811.html)

Comment: I don't know, I don't use Windows. =)

Comment: It reserves around 700mb for kernel driver address space near the top of the 4GB area, so that drivers can be put in fixed addresses. Or some such, I don't know the details, but it is reserved. You'll get roughly 3.3GB logical out of 4.0GB physical memory on a 32-bit Windows OS.

Comment: If you must use Windows XP, stay with 32-bit and deal with the memory limit of ~3gb. 64-bit XP is not very good; not many drivers targeted to it, has more than a few annoying bugs. If you need more than 3gb of ram, go for 64-bit Vista or 7.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum amount of memory that can be seen by 32bit WinXP is somewhere between 3 and 4 gigabytes depending on your chipset.

I have also run into issues running multiple instances of VS when I had resharper installed. The only thing you can do is run 64bit XP with more memory, or not use resharper (which is a bummer).

Answer (score 1):

32-bit Windows kernel divides the 4GB virtual addressing space in 2GB/2GB partitions. If you feed the /3GB switch to NTLDR it will offer 1GB kernel space / 3GB user mode space. Note that this NOT implies that you can't write software to take advantage of machines with 32-bit CPUs and address more than 4GB *at once*.

A workaround is the hardware-supported feature to access the remaining memory in banks or "windows" since the CPU still sees a maximum of 4GB addressable space at once. Some database and GIS software offer this possibility. This is called Physical Address Extensions and allows to use (not addressing at once) up to 64GB with 36-bit addresses. WinXP offers AWE, an API built on top of PAE.

That's the theory. For using Visual Studio you can get the full 4GB for your system or upgrade to a 64-bit OS with more RAM. This *only* if VS offers a 64-bit version.

Answer (score 0):

> "Also, any other ways of running multiple visual studio without such slow performance."

+1 trick: you should use a **RAM disk** ([download](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/05/27/free-ramdisk-for-windows-vista-xp-2000-and-2003-server/)) to accelerate I/O.

If you're using - and hopefully do - source-managament system (ie. Subversion), you must just checkout your projects there. VS.NET makes tons of I/O calls, and RAM disks are much faster than real disks.

**CAUTION!** If you turn off your computer, RAM Disk disappers.

Comment: Since 95% of computer programs follow the law of "locality of references", a RAM disk to accelerate memory is nearly of no effect when caching enters into play. That free RAM will be used by the NT cache manager automagically. For faster I/O, get faster hardware (includes max.RAM you can afford :))

Comment: Correction above: "RAM disk to accelerate I/O" ;)

Comment: I have good experiences while loading/building middle-sized solutions (>15 project, fxcop, nunit) on my notebook. 

(thanx for the correction!)